# $CurrentPage.Parameters.retURL null in Lightning but not Classic

Tags: visualforce, button-overrides

Using the following VF page that is an override of the Task's Delete button

*(Goal : Prevent any but Sysads from deleting Case completed Tasks)*

```
<apex:page id="TaskDelete" standardController="Task"
    action="{!IF (AND(  $Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator',
                        NOT(ISBLANK(Task.WhatId)),
                        LEFT(Task.WhatId,3) = '500',
                        Task.Status = 'Completed'
                        ),
                    NULL,
                    URLFOR($Action.Task.Delete,
                           Task.Id,
                           [retURL=$CurrentPage.parameters.retURL],
                           true)
                  )}">
    <apex:variable var="vWhatId" value="{!Task.WhatId}"/>
    <apex:variable var="vStatus" value="{!Task.Status}"/>
    <apex:pageMessage
            severity = "ERROR"
            strength = "3"
            title = "Task Delete"
            summary = "You are not allowed to delete completed Case Task records.">
    </apex:pageMessage>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

What I observe is that `$CurrentPage.parameters.retURL` is `\theCaseId` in Classic but null in LEX.

- So, how do I reliably, upon successful execution of `$Action.Task.Delete` go back to the page from whence the Task deletion was attempted (which could be the related list from an Sobject or simply a list of all the user's tasks) in both Classic and LEX?  *As a Task could have both WhoId and WhatId, no good way of unambiguously knowing entry point*
- Do I need to use an [Aura component for LEX standard button override](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/workshop-override-standard-action) and VF button override for Classic? **UPDATE**: *You can't override Delete buttons with a Lightning Component so this option is off the table*
- Should I just write a before delete trigger instead?

Here's the comparison between the VF page parameters in Classic v LEX when deletion was attempted from a Case's Activity History related list

**Classic**

```
_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN=xxxx
&common.udd.actions.ActionsUtilORIG_DELETE_URI=%2F00T6300000O5uuu%2Fd
&delID=00T6300000O5uuu
&id=00T6300000O5uuu
&retURL=%2F50063000009GLrT   <=== here is retURL
&sfdc.override=1
```

**LEX**

```
_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN=xxx
&clc=0
&delID=00T6300000O5uuu
&id=00T6300000O5uuu
&isdtp=p1
&lexiActionName=delete
&lexiSObjectName=Task
&ltn_app_id=06m630000003X8hAAE
&nonce=7ef66110f1c0a29cab756a33eef2fef24cd5eb9dbb4fc011ae0c655fa9486eb0&r=56
&sfdc.override=1
&sfdcIFrameHost=web
&sfdcIFrameOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fmydomain--xxx.lightning.force.com
&tour=
&ui-global-components-one-actionsManager.ActionsManager.handleAction=1
```